# Parse PFQuery Where value Doesn't Exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I need to perform a `PFQuery` where the key `code` is equal to any of the strings within an array.

So if I have an array of numbers like so: `@[@"1", @"2", @"3", nil]`

I want to query for any object of class `MyObject` where `code` matches any of the strings in the array.

How can I do this without doing multiple queries? I want to keep the requests down if possible as my array may contain as many as 100 strings.

Comment: Have you tried using `whereKey:containedIn:` method? https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:containedIn: